# Lua - How would I have a wait command for events without waiting for the wait to finish

Tags: lua

I have tried different wait/sleep commands which completely stops the code. In my code I have changed events, so if something was changed there is a wait/sleep command, but it will wait for that event to completely finish even if another event is called. How would I have it so there would still be a delay, but have it so the events called during the wait period will run, and not wait for the previous event.

Comment: I think you can do that with coroutines that yield to a scheduler.

Comment: I have a certain event that is called, i need it to run completely without stopping the cpu, just waiting in that specific function call.

Comment: The answer depends a bit on your operating system/platform.

If you're on Unix then you could do that with https://github.com/wahern/cqueues

Comment: Why are you trying to wait?  It sounds like you want to stop processing an event if another event comes in during processing that would negate the first event?  How long does processing the event take?

Comment: It takes about 7.2 seconds, i'm working on a cooldown system for my game, but sleep/wait pauses my whole game, which I believe is busy waiting, which is what I do not need. So Im switching over to coroutines

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1) "Fake" parallelism based on event loop:

Project "luvit" realizes this approach, trying to do for Lua those things that node.js doing for JavaScript. In my humble opinion, for such approach just use node.js, luvit is weird and is not very reliable.

2) Multi threading:

It is better for perfomance of application, but it is more complex way, it will take time to figure out how to work with it.
For this approach use Lua Lanes.

Also, if you need it inside OpenResty, it has tools for this.
If you need it in small script, though I love Lua with all my heart, you should consider switching to node.js